# Put divs or spans in td's

Tags: html, css

I have a basic table with a `td`'s.

I want to be able to put a coming soon sign over the top of the `td`. I have got the coming soon sign done with both divs and spans and i need both in to make the coming soon sign.

But I can't put the coming soon over the text in the `td`. The current result is they *end up on different lines*.

How can I put the text and the coming soon over the top of each other using css?

The wanted result will look similar to the minecraft home page:

[image: The wanted result]

Note: The coming soon sign is rotated so they can be told apart.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just putting the divs and spans in the td. when that didn't work i researched and didnt find anything

Comment: If possible please add full code, may be a fiddle. and also clear that do you want the Text to be hidden behind the coming soon or you want text and coming soon on same line?

Answer (score 1):

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  
}
.header{
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
table, th, td, .header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <h2 class="header">Comming soon</h2>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's very simple to "fake" what you are looking for with css as the table itself doesn't have any tag to achieve this.

I'm not really sure what you're actually trying to achieve so I did my best to translate your thoughts into something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding only the span element (the div implies a line break)

```
<td>Text 1<span class="b">Coming Soon</span>text 2</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

or may be this helps-
http://jsbin.com/zicoxakuzu/1/edit?html,output

```
<table>
  <th>Text</th>
  <th></th>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td><div class="a"><span class="b">Coming Soon</span></div> </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td><div class="a"><span class="b">Coming Soon</span></div> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsbin.com/zicoxakuzu/edit?html,output
 i think this is what you what ..check this out.

```
<body>
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <div class="a"><span class="b">Coming Soon</span></div>
      text1</td>

  </tr>
   <tr>

    <td><div class="a"><span class="b">Coming Soon</span></div>
      text2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Did this help? @James Plen